# How to get X and Y axis for screen in dp android studio

Tags: java, android, textview, axis

I have a text view onTick that needs to change its position on the screen every 1 sec. I have a method to give me a random value between 0 and the max height/width of the screen. The issue is I'm hardcoding the values and this won't work on other devices with a smaller or bigger screen. Any advice on how to make that no matter the size of the screen my view will still be changing its position without going off-screen? I have tried other methods/functions as well but they don't work or/are deprecated. Here is the code of the function/method:

```
   public float generateXAndY(int x, int y) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return rnd.nextInt((y - x)) + x;
    }

textViewEgnDisplay.setX(generateXAndY(0,1570));
textViewEgnDisplay.setY(generateXAndY(0,782));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with post method

```
textview.post(new runnable{
Setx(generateXandY())
})
```

Comment: Im looking for values or formula but thanks anyway